# Python-2.7: No SIGINT possible in while loop with locks

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, locks, sigint

I implemented a while loop with locks in python-2.7 (see example) to handle two lists which are loaded with values by an other thread each.
The code works, but it will not handle SIGINT (Ctrl-C) anymore. 
Example:

```
while True:
  with lock1:
    if 0 < len(data_buf1):
      foo(data_buf1.pop(0))
  with lock2:
    if 0 < len(data_buf2):
      bar(data_buf2.pop(0)
```

What could I do to enable keyboard commands again?

**Update**
The loop runs in the main python process.

Comment: signals and threads do not mix well. It's possible that only the main thread will receive the signals... See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads), quote: *Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread, even if the signal was received in another thread. This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. You can use the synchronization primitives from the threading module instead.*

Comment: Thank you, I forget to mention that my loop is in the main process.

Comment: What are the types of `lock1` and `lock2`?

Comment: allocate_lock from the module thread

Comment: Do we need locks at all? Updating mutable data from distinct threads is not the whole reason for why we have the GIL?

Comment: Your code works for me. I can still CTRL-C out of `lock = thread.allocate_lock(); with lock: while 1: pass`, so it may be another issue.

Comment: Thx, I will check it. 
The other threads are ROS callbacks. I relized a minute ago, that they stop working after pressing CTRL-C. So, signals come trough and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @PauloScardine No. The GIL only prevents the threads to switch between *bytecodes*. It is used to make so that things like reference counts and GC can be implemented easily.